# Set colors in stacked bar plot per SEMI-known Label

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, seaborn

I asked a similar question before which was answered perfectly.

[Set colors in stacked bar plot per label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154337/set-colors-in-stacked-bar-plot-per-label?noredirect=1#comment98940270_56154337)

```
def gen_colors(df):
    col_d = {'B1': 'red', 'B2': 'black', 'B3': 'green'}
    return [col_d[col] for col in df.columns if 'B' in col]


sns.set()

d = {'DAY': [55,56,58,65], 'B1': [2,6,6,1],  'B2': [1,0,21,0], 'B3': [0,1,0,1]}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
data1.set_index('DAY').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=gen_colors(data1))
```

[image: works]

Now I am building on that for example, what if we don't know the label extension. (There is no way of knowing the label extensions in advance, and they will come with names like B1_Active, B2_Missing, B3_Double.. (The name after the B* is called the status of the box)

```
def gen_colors(df):
    col_d = {'B1': 'red','B1_Missing': 'firebrick', 'B2': 'black', 'B3': 'green'}
    return [col_d[col] for col in df.columns if 'B' in col]

t = {'DAY': [55,56,58,65], 'B1_Active': [2,6,6,1],  'B3_Missing': [0,1,0,1]}
    toy1 = pd.DataFrame(data = t)

    try:
        toy1.set_index('DAY').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=gen_colors(toy1))
    except:
        toy1.set_index('DAY').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

This is just resulting to colors to be randomly selected. How can I make a dictionary to give different shades of colors of red when the label starts with B1 for example B1_Active = red, B1_Missing = firebrick etc.. My point is I want to keep the main color same for all combinations of B1 but add a slight shade to differentiate the status.. is this possible? I searched on "catch all" dictionary but could not work with regex.. Thanks

[image]

Also this is the palette:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your label extensions have the format B{number}_{status}. Consider we call them labex. The split function from the regular expression library allows you to separate the status from the rest. For example

```
import re
labex = 'B1_Active'
re.split(r'_', labex)
# ['B1', 'Active']
```

Now I will consider that you know how many B and status possibilities there are. You can simply use a defaultdict (imported from collections) to store your colours according to the B value and a list to store the index given to each status.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
colours = defaultdict(list)
colours['B1'] = ['xkcd:red', 'xkcd:bright red', 'xkcd:crimson']
colours['B2'] = ['xkcd:green', 'xkcd:grass green', 'xkcd:forest green']
colours['B3'] = ['xkcd:blue', 'xkcd:sky blue', 'xkcd:cerulean']
status = ['Active', 'Missing', 'Double']
labex = 'B2_Missing'
colours[re.split(r'_', labex)[0]][status.index(re.split(r'_', labex)[1])]
# xkcd:grass green
```

This should give you a place to start. The status values do not have to be known in advance, as you can simply initialise status as '[]' and append to it new values as you encounter them. The same logic applies for the B values, but you need to have either way somewhere in memory the colour shades stored, or you need to be able to generate them on the fly.